# Can GetStringCritical cause deadlock?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, deadlock

There is a deadlock happened in system_server,and the lock is hold by PackageManager.

```
"PackageManager" prio=5 tid=27 WaitingForGcToComplete
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d3e7b0 self=0xb865c1a0
  | sysTid=579 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb865c788
  | state=S schedstat=( 82300981 68593861 146 ) utm=6 stm=2 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0xa0fdb000-0xa0fdd000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  native: #00 pc 00012960  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
  native: #01 pc 000a88ad  /system/lib/libart.so(art::Mutex::ExclusiveLock(art::Thread*)+364)
  native: #02 pc 0013aa7b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::Heap::IncrementDisableMovingGC(art::Thread*)+90)
  native: #03 pc 001c0329  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::GetStringCritical(_JNIEnv*, _jstring*, unsigned char*)+392)
  native: #04 pc 00082223  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
  native: #05 pc 00082291  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
  native: #06 pc 00263595  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (Java_android_os_Parcel_nativeWriteString__JLjava_lang_String_2+120)
  at android.os.Parcel.nativeWriteString(Native method)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeString(Parcel.java:542)
  at android.content.ComponentName.writeToParcel(ComponentName.java:267)
  at android.content.ComponentName.writeToParcel(ComponentName.java:282)
  at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7486)
  at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleUnbindService(ApplicationThreadNative.java:929)
  at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.removeConnectionLocked(ActiveServices.java:1842)
  at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.unbindServiceLocked(ActiveServices.java:943)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.unbindService(ActivityManagerService.java:15787)
  - locked <0x1d3e13e9> (a com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService)
```

So I google it and find out if there is some other JNI calls between GetStringCritical and ReleaseStringCritical,deadlock may happen if GC is blocked.
For see more detail [The Java Native Interface: Programmer's Guide and Specification](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=8M3F_sSSvWkC&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=GetStringCritical%20deadlock&source=bl&ots=Qm64TaIZgg&sig=zyCFkcZABe2RRvxAhJlXx9gbllE&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikqfX18ofUAhWHtpQKHaRKCX8Q6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=GetStringCritical%20deadlock&f=false)

This is part of method android_os_Parcel_writeString in frameworks\base\core\jni\android_os_Parcel.cpp.

```
    const jchar* str = env->GetStringCritical(val, 0);
    if (str) {
        err = parcel->writeString16(str, env->GetStringLength(val));
        env->ReleaseStringCritical(val, str);
    }
```

I can not sure deadlock is cause by android_os_Parcel_writeString because android_os_Parcel_writeString is a very commonly used method.

So I'm asking is android_os_Parcel_writeString may cause deadlock?

Thank you for your answer and forget my awkward English.

Answer (score 0):

`GetStringCritical` must be used with extreme care. You must
make sure that while holding a pointer obtained through `GetStringCritical`, the native code does not allocate new objects in the JVM or perform other blocking calls that may cause the system to deadlock.

```
    /* This is not safe! */
const char *c_str = (*env)->GetStringCritical(env, j_str, 0);
if (c_str == NULL) {
... /* error handling */
}
fprintf(fd, "%s\n", c_str);
(*env)->ReleaseStringCritical(env, j_str, c_str);
```

The problem with the code is that it is not always safe to write to a file
handle when garbage collection is disabled by the current thread. For
example, that another `thread T` is waiting to read from the `fd` file handle. Let us
further assume that the operating system buffering is set up in such a way that the
`fprintf` call waits until the `thread T` finishes reading all pending data from `fd`. We
have constructed a possible scenario for deadlocks: If `thread T` cannot allocate
enough memory to serve as a buffer for reading from the file handle, it must
request a garbage collection. The garbage collection request will be blocked until
the current thread executes `ReleaseStringCritical`, which cannot happen until
the `fprintf` call returns. The `fprintf` call is waiting, however, for `thread T` to finish reading from the file handle

After looking at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android_os_Parcel.cpp, the method `writeString16` is deadlock free. I never see any issue with `Parcel` so far.